# Error in crystal report job in documentum

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, wdk, documentum, webtop

We are getting the below error message in the view job report option while executing the method named drs_RunReportMethod  through a job named drs_crystal job in documentum for converting the crystal reports placed /Reports cabinet from .rpt to .pdf. Kindly provide your suggestions on this.

Below are the arguments of the method I have set:-

```
-report_output_file_format pdf, -purge_limit 5, -report_user_name dmadmin, -report0_parameter Document|Name=Design|Document, Top|N|Records=25, Show|Chart=1, -report0 /Reports/test.rpt, -report_output_docbase_path /Reports
```

ERROR MESSAGE OF THE JOB REPORT:

```
2016-02-07 11:24:48 UTC:  ERROR: ERROR - Processing of report :/Reports/test.rpt failed with error DmDRSException:: THREAD: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2; MSG: [DM_DRS_E_EXCEPTION_ERROR]error:  "[DM_DRS_E_EXCEPTION_ERROR]: Exception Class:class java.lang.Exception: Message:Report handler class is not configured for the report format: rpt: Cause:null: Exception Detail:java.lang.Exception: Report handler class is not configured for the report format: rpt: Stack Trace 
java.lang.Exception: Report handler class is not configured for the report format: rpt
  at com.documentum.drs.method.RunReportMethod.getReportHandler(RunReportMethod.java:558)
  at com.documentum.drs.method.RunReportMethod.exportReport(RunReportMethod.java:403)
  at com.documentum.drs.method.RunReportMethod.processReport(RunReportMethod.java:368)
  at com.documentum.drs.method.RunReportMethod.processReports(RunReportMethod.java:255)
  at com.documentum.drs.method.RunReportMethod.execute(RunReportMethod.java:155)
  at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DmMethodRunner.runIt(Unknown Source)
  at com.documentum.mthdservlet.AMethodRunner.runAndReturnStatus(Unknown Source)
  at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
  at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.doPost(Unknown Source)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: I never heard of this job and I did check the documentation to see what I have missed. It seems that this job isn't shipped with platform. Am I right?

Comment: job i have created and added the method in it. Method is OOTB[drs_RunReportMethod]. I have added in my initial post the aruments I have passed for this method.